# Building MaxHeap Largest Not Being Sent To Top

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, heap

I am trying to build a max heap out of a vector of size 10. It contains numbers 1-10. Yet my program will not set the largest value 10 to the largest variable because when comparing it exceeds my vector's range.

```
if ((l <= v.size()) && (v.at(l) > v.at(i)))
    {largest = l;}
    else { largest = i; }

    if ((r <= v.size()) && (v.at(r) > v.at(largest))) // r at some point is 10. which exceeds v.
    {largest = r;}
```

I tried setting an if statement around the code above that would catch the error, but then i get this:

```
INPUT:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
OUTPUT: 9 8 7 4 5 6 3 2 1 10
```

Which is almost correct, but the 10 should be first. What can I do to make sure the heap builds correctly? Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


vector<string> readFile(string fileName) { /* read in file. Works Fine.*/}
void display(vector<string>& v)  {/*displays vector. works fine. */  }

inline int parent(int i){return i / 2; }
inline int left(int i)  {return 2*i;}
inline int right(int i) {return 2*i + 1;}

void Max_Heapify(vector<string>& v, int i)
{
    int largest;
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    i--;

    if ((l <= v.size()) && (v.at(l) > v.at(i)))  
    {largest = l;}
    else { largest = i; }

    if ((r <= v.size()) && (v.at(r) > v.at(largest)))
    {
        largest = r;
    }

    if (largest != i)
    {
        string temp = v.at(i);
        v.at(i) = v.at(largest);
        v.at(largest) = temp;

        Max_Heapify(v, largest);
    }
}

void Build_Max_Heap(vector<string>& v, int length) 
{
    for (int i = (length / 2); i > 0; i--)
    {
        Max_Heapify(v, i);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<string> vectorReadIn;
    vector<string> sortedVector;
    int x = 0;

    string fileName = "C:/Users/user/Downloads/Algorithims/Perm Words/perm15k.txt";

    vectorReadIn = readFile(fileName);

    cout << "Unsorted file:" << endl;
    display(vectorReadIn);
    vectorReadIn.resize(vectorReadIn.size());
    Build_Max_Heap(vectorReadIn, vectorReadIn.size());

    display(vectorReadIn);  
}
```

Comment: Valid indexes into a vector of size `N` are 0 through `N-1`. Therefore, when `l == v.size()`, then `v.at(l)` is going to throw out-of-range exception. In light of this, the condition `((l <= v.size()) && (v.at(l) > v.at(i)))` looks wrong - `v.at(l)` is only valid when `l` is strictly less than `v.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment by Igor Tandetnik, your calculations for left and right child are wrong. In a vector with index 0 being the first item, the root of your heap is at index 0. So the calculations for left and right child are:

```
left child: (2*x) + 1
right child: (2*x) + 2
```

The calculations you have are for a heap with the root at index 1.

Also, the loop in your `Build_Max_Heap` function needs to be:

```
for (int i = (length / 2); i >= 0; i--)
```

That is, you must check to see if the first item in the vector needs to be rearranged.